# Java Array String Compare

Tags: java, compare

Hi everyone i'm  trying to compare a array and i want to print the letters in common between the position [0] and the [1]

example in the array[0] i have something like  a[0]=aokk
and in the other position i have one that say  a[1]=ok;

i want the problem to print only the letter that are in the position 0 and too in the 
what i'm doing is

```
for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length(); j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a[1].length(); i++) {
        if (a[0].charAt(i) == b[1].charAt(j)) {
            common += a[0].charAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

but i'm getting as a output  "okk" when when it should be  "ok" because the K is only once in the position [0]

Comment: That's because you check every character in the first against every in the second and since there's two `k`s in the first your algo detects the common character twice. Also, "the K is only once in the position [0]" is not true; it's only once in `[1]` per your example.

Comment: Is this link relevant? [Longest common subsequence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)

Comment: `a` is your array containing your two strings. What is `b`? You are referring to `b[1].charAt(j)` in your code.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Can you tell me now is it correct or not?

Comment: Does the order of letters matter? For "cast" and "stay", would either "a", "st" or "ast" count as a valid answer?

Comment: @OleV.V. yeah my bad i wrote wrong the code   i didn't copy page my code i write it , and i was kinda sleep  and the order doenst matter

Comment: @YashMehta yes this works thanks u <3

Comment: So if I understand correctly, for "cast" and "stay", correct answers include "ast" and "sta", while neither of "a" and "st" suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Solution{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String arr[] = {"aokk","ok"};
        List<Integer> index = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<arr[0].length();i++){
            for(int j=0;j<arr[1].length();j++){
                if(arr[0].charAt(i)==arr[1].charAt(j) && index.contains(j)==false){
                    System.out.print(arr[0].charAt(i)); //print if it matches
                    index.add(j);//add index to list so it won't count again
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks u  i wish i could give u thumb up but since i'm a new  user i cant do it

Comment: then please can you accept this answer as right answer?

Comment: Nice. Just a detail: rather than `index.contains(j)==false` I’d prefer `! index.contains(j)` (the exclamation mark means ‘not’ — in Java and in very many other languages).

Answer (score 1):

The problem of this algorithm is that you are comparing two strings with different length. In this case, the string with a shorter length finishes its loop earlier than another string does, so the shorter one its index remains at the last element, which is "k". Another string its loop still keeps going on, and when it reaches the letter "k", your if condition is true(since "k" == "k"), that's why you will have double k.

Answer (score 0):

try remove duplicate from common：

```
List<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
for (char ch : common.toCharArray()) {
            list.add(ch);
}
return new HashSet<>(list).toString();
```

Comment: It will not work for like a[0]="Butter" and a[1]="Button", output should be Butt not But. or like a[0]="okkk" and a[1]="kk" then it will be kk not k.

Comment: This yeids `[k, o]`. Could be improved, of course: add the chars from the set to a StringBuilder and use this for building the new string. Also I’m in doubt whether the OP wants to get rid of all duplicates; what if a letter comes twice (or more) in both the original strings?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PrintCommonLetters {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Strings in array for comparison
        String[] array = {"ok","aokk", "ko"};

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++)
        {
            for(int j = i + 1; j <= array.length - 1; j++)
            {   
                // Compare which string is longer
                if(array[i].length() > array[j].length())
                {
                    // Found substring array[j] in array[i]
                    if(array[i].contains(array[j]))
                        System.out.println(array[j]);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Found substring array[i] in array[j]
                    if(array[j].contains(array[i]))
                        System.out.println(array[i]);
                }               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If ordering is not important then you can use below code.
You can sort both of the array and then alter merge sort for comparison common in strings.

```
public static String commonInArray(char[] char1, char[] char2) {
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    String common = "";

    while(i < char1.length) {
        if(char1[i] == char2[j]) {
            common += char1[i];
            i++;
            j++;
        } else if(char1[i] > char2[j]) {
            j++;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }

    return common;
} 

public static void main (String[] args) {
    // Strings in array for comparison
    String[] array = {"bitter","letter"};

    char[] char1 = array[0].toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(char1);

    char[] char2 = array[1].toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(char2);

    String common;

    if(char1.length > char2.length) {
        common = commonInArray(char1, char2);
    } else {
        common = commonInArray(char2, char1);
    }

    System.out.println(common);
}
```

Alternate Solution:

1) Store first string in linked list

2) Traverse second string

3) Remove common element from linked list

```
    String[] a = {"aokk", "ok"};
    String common = "";

    LinkedList<Character> store = new LinkedList<Character>();

    for(int i = 0; i < a[0].length(); i++) {
        store.add(a[0].charAt(i));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a[1].length(); i++) {
        if(store.contains(a[1].charAt(i))) {
            common += a[1].charAt(i);
            store.remove(store.indexOf(a[1].charAt(i)));
        }
    }

    System.out.println(common);
```

Comment: Not really Java style code, and doesn’t report duplicates: I believe common of "letter" and "bitter" will be "ter", not "tter". Otherwise a nice idea.

Comment: The code has been improved as per java style and also it giving desired result.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
1.Assuming in your case,that in String array , a[0] has maximum length
2.Of course, you can get the maximum length from the string array you can choose the max length and you can modify the length and do according to your requirement.                                
3. For now, check the following :

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

String a[]={"aokk","ok"};
String common = "";
 for(int i=0;i < a[1].length();i++)
 {
  for(int j=0; j<a[0].length();j++) 
  {
    if(a[1].charAt(i) == a[0].charAt(j) && common.indexOf(a[0].charAt(j))<0)
    {
       common = common + a[0].charAt(j);
    }
  }
 }
  System.out.println(common);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There’s a lovely wealth of solutions already, each with their strengths and weaknesses. I’ll put in my suggestion. I am assuming that order of letters is not important, but if a letter occurs twice in each string, it must also occur twice in the result.

```
/** @return chars common to a[0] and a[1] */
public static String commonChars(String[] a) {
    int[] charCounts = new int[256];
    for (int index = 0; index < a[0].length(); index++) {
        charCounts[a[0].charAt(index)]++;
    }
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(a[0].length());
    for (int index = 0; index < a[1].length(); index++) {
        if (charCounts[a[1].charAt(index)] > 0) {
            result.append(a[1].charAt(index));
            charCounts[a[1].charAt(index)]--;
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Strengths in my own judgement: Takes into account that a letter may occur twice (as in Button and Butter, or letter and bitter). Fairly efficient (which probably doesn’t matter). And in case it matters, the letters generally come out in the same order as found in `a[1]`.

Weakness I’m aware of: breaks down with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if either string contains a character outside the Latin-1 range (0 through 255) or `a` is shorter than 2.